# Displaying form data using angular and spring

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, forms

I am trying to display form data taken from User using angular js and sending the data to Java springs to display it on console.

Yes. Am beginner in Angularjs. So would like to know how to get this done.

My html Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>


   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


   <title>Insert title here</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var ang= angular.module('test',[]);
  ang.controller('UserController',function ($scope, $http) {
   var user = {
        name : $scope.name,
        email : $scope.email,
        };  

$scope.createUser = function() {

    //alert("Insided...");
    $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'src/com/createuser',
        data : $scope.user,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
    .error(function(data){
        alert( "failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
    });
}
 });






    </script>

   <body data-ng-app="test" data-ng-controller="UserController">
      <form  data-ng-submit="createUser()">

    <legend>Create User</legend>
    <label>Name</label> 
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" data-ng-model="name" placeholder="User Name"> 
    <label>email</label>
    <input type="text" id="pwd" name="pwd" data-ng-model="email" placeholder="ur own pwd here">

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>

</form>
```

My java code:

```
 package com.userdisplay;

 import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;


     @Controller
   public class createuser {
   @RequestMapping(value="/createuser",method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public  @ResponseBody String details( @RequestParam("name") String name,
                                        @RequestParam("email") String email)
        {       
    System.out.print(name);
    return "the details are name" + name + ", email" + email+ "yes.";

 }

}
```

Comment: what are the errors? What do the console.log in angular and the print in java output?

Comment: It gives an alert message saying: "failure message: {"data":null}".

Comment: At console, it gives me this error:
Error: Access to restricted URI denied
Sf/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:93:113
q@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:89:64
m/g<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:86:220
f/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:118:216

Comment: your data-ng-model attributes should be user.name and user.email, and in the $scope declare $scope.user={name: "", email:""}

Comment: Done with the changes. Still gives an error.

Comment: Did you open your html directly from the file or did you call it from the server (in your browser the url bar says C:\Something\index.html or /home/something/index.html instead of http://localhost/index.html ? )

Comment: Are you using spring boot to run the html file? Do you have the REST service running and available?

Comment: Am using Eclipse, Tomcat 7 to run this code.

Below is the URL location used to run this code.
http://localhost:8080/shop6/

Project name is shop6